# Editing UITableviewCell when table is inside scroll view not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to put a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView`. The *scroll view* is a horizontal paging setup to switch between a few pages/views.
One of those views has a table with editable cells. **The problem arises when I try to swipe horizontally on the table to edit them**. The *scroll view* captures the swipe first and pages over. I know the `tableview` is collecting touches because I can scroll vertically on it no problem.

As soon as I disable scrolling on the `scrollview` I can swipe to edit the cells in the table.

**Is there anyway to get it so I can swipe on the table to edit cells but then still scroll on the view if I don't swipe on the table, or a header of the table that isn't editable?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass the UIScrollView and implement below method
    - (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view

This will make the UIScrollView to pass on touches to content view which is UITableview.